# What is the lowest time resolution for somewhat accurate measurements of cpu usage?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, performance

Some of the things I want to measure are very short,and I can only repeat them so many times if I don't run any of the setup/dispose code in the middle.

note: on linux,reading /proc/stat

Comment: Do you therefore mean "*highest* time resolution"?

Answer (score 0):

Not very portable and you'll have to take great care so it is reliable, but the [Time Stamp Counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) definitely has the highest resolution available (increases at every CPU tick).

> The time stamp counter has, until
>   recently, been an excellent
>   high-resolution, low-overhead way of
>   getting CPU timing information. With
>   the advent of multi-core/hyperthreaded
>   CPUs, systems with multiple CPUs, and
>   "hibernating" operating systems, the
>   TSC cannot be relied on to provide
>   accurate results - unless great care
>   is taken to correct the possible
>   flaws: rate of tick and whether all
>   cores (processors) have identical
>   values in their time-keeping
>   registers. There is no promise that
>   the timestamp counters of multiple
>   CPUs on a single motherboard will be
>   synchronized. In such cases,
>   programmers can only get reliable
>   results by locking their code to a
>   single CPU. Even then, the CPU speed
>   may change due to power-saving
>   measures taken by the OS or BIOS, or
>   the system may be hibernated and later
>   resumed (resetting the time stamp
>   counter). In those latter cases, to
>   stay relevant, the counter must be
>   recalibrated periodically (according
>   to the time resolution your
>   application requires).

There's some notes there about Linux specific solutions on the page, too:

> Under Linux, similar functionality is
>   provided by reading the value of
>   CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock using POSIX
>   clock_gettime function.